# Circular Button not working on android API-16 (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I want to create a simple **circular ImageButton** as shown below, which is supported in android API versions of 16 or higher.

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="70dp"
 android:layout_height="70dp"
 android:id="@+id/myButton"
 android:background="@drawable/circular_button" />
```

My **circular_button.xml** inside drawable folder looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#fa09ad"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#c20586"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Things work fine on android Lollipop (API 21) and this how the ImageButton looks:

[image]

But on older android versions (API 16), it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea how to get this solved?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using ImageView instead?

Comment: your image are not loading. add them again

Comment: I have tried but that did not work as well. Also, I require a circular button that has both drawable icon and text inside it. @Sheychan

Comment: @VivekMishra, basically in android API-21 the circular button comes as expected with the content's background color. But in API-16 or API-17, it comes as a plain square button and the background color also does not fill up.

Comment: @user3500989 Where is the drawable saved? on res/drawable or res/drawable-v21?

Comment: Its inside res/drawable folder. I have been able to use drawables successfully throughout the app, hence I do not see an issue with that. @ Sheychan

Comment: It works fine on both API 16 and API 21. Created a new blank activity and used your code. Nothing else. Recheck.

Comment: @Arpan, ideally it should work, but for some reason it is not in my code.

Comment: Used Imageview instead of ImageButton ?

Comment: That's why I asked you to recheck your code. Share your code (pastebin). Either try the same code in a new blank project see if works or same problem else try some other emulator image/devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** My Mistake: Please try below code, i used it in my own code and it is working perfectly for round images.

```
public class ImageHelper {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the explanation of why this will fix the issue?

Comment: This did not fixed the issue! @Android Geek

Comment: @user3500989 if you facing problem in using this code, you can ask.

Comment: @user3500989 Great, WC :) You can upvote too thanks :)